# Expression Body VS Block Body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnet-compiler

While coding, a discrepancy surfaced.  Normally while coding simple methods or constructors I often utilize the expression body technique.  However, when I produce the following:

```
public class Sample : ISample
{
     private readonly IConfigurationRoot configuration;

     public Sample(IConfigurationRoot configuration) => this.configuration = configuration;
}
```

The code appears to be valid, Visual Studio and compile both work.  The issue though comes if inside that same class, I go to use the `configuration` variable.  It produces *"A field initializer cannot  reference a non static field initializer."*

That syntax usage that produced:

```
var example = configuration.GetSection("Settings:Key").Value;
```

However, if I leave the snippet above this and modify to a block body.  Visual Studio no longer freaks out, why would an expression body cause such a peculiar error?  While the block body works correctly with snippet above?

```
public class Sample : ISample
{
     private readonly IConfigurationRoot configuration;

     public Sample(IConfigurationRoot configuration)
     {
           this.configuration = configuration;
     }
}
```

---

```
public class ApplicationProvider
{
     public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; } = CreateConfiguration();

     public IServiceProvider BuildProvider()
     {
         var services = new ServiceCollection();
         DependencyRegistration(services);

         return services.AddLogging().BuildServiceProvider();
     }

     private IConfigurationRoot CreateConfiguration() => new ConfigurationBuilder()
     .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
     .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
     .Build();

     private void DependencyRegistration(this IServiceCollection services)
     {
          services.AddSingleton(_ => Configuration);
          // All other dependency registration would also go here.
     }
}

public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; } = new ApplicationProvider().BuildProvider();
```

I would have an interface for class, then instantiate by pulling from the provider.

```
ISample sample = ServiceProvider.GetServices<ISample>();
```

Comment: @CalC Weird right?  I'm trying to dig into the Microsoft Dependency Injection Framework for Core, thinking it might be there or in another location.  But no matter what I do, that error appears inside this core 2.0 application.

Comment: Can you add more information showing how you create an instance of the Sample class?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. The code you've shown should be fine *in a method*. If you're trying to declare a field, you can't declare it with `var` anyway.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm confused by the `var` comment, the example I have with a `var` is trying to read the field to retrieve the value.  Not per se use. Could you clarify please?

Comment: It's trying to declare a variable called `example`, which you can't do using var if you're trying to make that variable a field. Basically, we're guessing what your code really looks like because you haven't provided us with a [mcve]. It's easy to stop the speculation: provide a complete example.

Comment: @Greg For example, I tried to replicate the issue last night. 
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/40245623#40245623
Using DotNetFiddle and the Roslyn compiler, I was able to get similar code to run without issue.  However, I completely assumed the `var example` line was a member function or something similar.  Also, if you are using a framework to perform the dependency injection for you -- as suggested by your comments -- that is important to know.

Comment: I've updated, it is Asp.Net Core 2.0 utilizing all of the new Core Microsoft.Extensions.

Comment: @Greg Does Sample implement ISample?  Assuming it does.  Is that class definition located in a class?  Otherwise, `public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; } = new ApplicationProvider().BuildProvider();` doesn't work.

Comment: @TylerStahlhuth Yes, I updated question.

Comment: @Greg I see a lot of problems with the code you provided, but am still futzing with trying to get AspNetCore to install so I am unable to test it.  Are you sure the code provided compiles?

Comment: I ask because you have a non-static extension method in a non-static class.

Comment: @TylerStahlhuth I may have made typos, I did it really quick and a system went down, so I've been distracted. I'll fix in a bit.  The `static` is in a whole different class.

Comment: @Greg This Gist works just fine when I created a Asp project and used the classes without anything else going on.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a9f7a9a85399a6f6e323896e737608b5

Comment: @TylerStahlhuth Hm, weird. I wonder why Visual Studio flags.

Comment: @Greg Wait, it flags it?  Does it actually build?  Are you sure that error message isn't `A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property`

If so, it's this line that is the problem:
`public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; } = CreateConfiguration();`

Comment: @TylerStahlhuth That line has been popping out at me.  When I have a chance I'll let you know.

Comment: @Greg The reason my version works is because I made the CreateConfiguration method static.